# Use Integration by parts to prove the following reduction formula...

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Use integration by parts to prove the reduction formula $$\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = - {\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)\over n}+{n-1\over n}\int\sin^{n-2}(x)\ dx$$

So I'm definitely on the right track because I'm very close to this result, and I also found an example of this exact question in one of my textbooks.

I made f(x)=$\sin^{n-1}(x)$ and g'(x)=$\sin(x)$. And with that I got to the point of having

$\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = - \sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)+(n-1)\int\cos^2(x)\sin^{n-2}(x)\ dx$

(sorry I haven't shown how I got to this stage, It's taking me way too long to write out these formulas, but the textbook done the same thing)

Then the textbook then uses the identity $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$.

Which would give:

$\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = - \sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)+(n-1)\int(1-\sin^2(x))\sin^{n-2}(x)\ dx$

And then I would have thought expanding that last integral would give

$\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = - \sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)+(n-1)\int\sin^{n-2}(x)-\int\sin^n(x))\\ dx$

However the textbook says you should get

$\int\sin^n(x)\ dx = - \sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)+(n-1)\int\sin^{n-2}(x)-(n-1)\int\sin^n(x))\\ dx$

Lots of information but essentially my question is just this, where did that extra (n-1) come from? I can't figure it out and its preventing me from finishing the question.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The $(n-1)$ term multiplies two terms, not just one. Check your calculation after the words "Which would give"

Comment: Ahh I see, silly mistake. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the $n-1$ term is multiplying everything against the integral on the right hand side; namely the term
\begin{equation}
(n-1)\left(\int(1-\sin^2(x))\sin^{n-2}(x)dx\right) 
\end{equation} 
As such once multiplied out; the $n-1$ term appears agains the $-\int \sin^{n}(x)dx$ term too.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\displaystyle I_{n} = \int \sin^n xdx = \int \sin^{n-1}x\cdot \sin xdx $$

Now Using Integration by parts , we get

$$\displaystyle I_{n}  = -\sin^{n-1}x\cdot \cos x+(n-1)\int \sin^{n-2}x\cdot \cos x\cdot \cos xdx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I_{n}  = -\sin^{n-1}x\cdot \cos x+(n-1)\int \sin^{n-2}x\cdot \cos^ 2x\cdot dx$$

So $$\displaystyle I_{n}  = -\sin^{n-1}x\cdot \cos x+(n-1)\int \sin^{n-2}x\cdot \left(1-\sin^ 2 x\right)dx$$

So $$\displaystyle I_{n}  = -\sin^{n-1}x\cdot \cos x+(n-1)\int \sin^{n-2}xdx-(n-1)\int \sin^2 xdx$$

So $$\displaystyle I_{n} = -\sin^{n-1}x\cdot \cos x+(n-1)I_{n-2}-(n-1)I_{n}$$

So $$\displaystyle (1+n-1)I_{n} = -\sin^{n-1}x\cdot \cos x+(n-1)I_{n-2}$$

So $$\displaystyle I_{n} = -\frac{1}{n}\sin^{n-1}x\cos x+\frac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track.

We have
$$
\int_{x} \sin^{n}x = -\int_{x}\sin^{n-1}x D\cos x = -\cos x \sin^{n-1}(x) + (n-1) \int_{x} \cos^{2}x \sin^{n-2}x =\\ -\cos x\sin^{n-1}x + {\color{red}{(n-1)\int_{x}(1-\sin^{2}x)\sin^{n-2}x}}.
$$